# Passing tuple returned by function to other function

Tags: ruby, parameter-passing

Considering two functions

```
def bar()
  return 1,2
end

def foo(a,b)
  puts %{#{a},#{b}}
end
```

I would like to be able to call `foo` both with explicit parameters (e.g. `foo(3,4)`) as well as with parameters returned by `bar` (e.g. `foo(bar)`).

Unfortunately, the 2nd call produces an ArgumentError: "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)".

Declaring `foo()` to take a tuple (`def foo(c); a,b = c; puts %{#{a},#{b}}; end`) doesn't work either, because then the 1st call parameter raises the ArgumentError.

I thought of defining `foo` to take a Hash:

```
def foo(c)
  a,b = c['a'],c['b']
  puts %{#{a},#{b}}
end
```

but this makes the use with explicit parameters rather unhandy. Same with an Array.

What's the Ruby-esque way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to splat the two-element array returned by `bar`: `foo(*bar)`. That’s because `foo` has two arguments, each an element of the array returned by `bar`, not one argument that is that array.

Recall that the splat operator converts `foo(*[1,2])` to `foo(1,2)`.